# Image and Label is not in desired alignment of button C# / WPF / XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want background image on left side of button and text overlayed on image in middle, but what I get is: [image]

what I want is: [image]

the clipart is PNG: [image] with transparency set

Ok, I found the solution:

```
<Button x:Name="btnCustomer"
        Click="btnCustomer_Click">
    <Button.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Image Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=btnCustomer}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Source="Images\Customer.png"
                   Stretch="Uniform" />
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"><Bold>Our Customer</Bold></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Its output image is: [image]

Comment: still not working. please see updated code.

Comment: I want the image to be behind text. Text is overlaid. image starts from left and text is in the middle. like 2 layers. background layer is image starting from left, and front layer is text in middle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to setting appropriate alignments of the elements in the Grid inside the Button's Content, you should also set some sensible maximum height of the Image, and perhaps also a sensible horizontal text margin:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Image Source="Images/Customer.png" MaxHeight="20"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Customer" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="20,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```xml
<Button x:Name="btnCustomer">
    <Button.Content>
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image
                Grid.Column="0"
                Source="Images\Customer.png"
                Stretch="Uniform" />
            <TextBlock Margin="6, 0"
                Grid.Column="1"  
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Text="Customer" />
        </Grid>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Comment: in stackpanel the image eats the space for text, because they are stacked left to right. text has to be overlaid and image in background. Some text has to go in the transparent space of background image so that it maintains the center. See my yesterday problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60365836/how-to-make-an-image-backgroud-in-button-zoom-shrink-vertically-maintaining-the I have like 50 buttons with different cliparts, all have transparency and text starts from the transparent portion of image and stays in center

Comment: I found the solution, it was to bind the button content with the width of the button to get proper left / center / right alignments etc.